# Proof using piegeonhole principle

Tags: pigeonhole-principle

how can I prove that In every collection of 51 integers between 1 and 100 there are at least two whose sum is 101.

I could't come upwith a solution please help

Comment: try to include thoughts and attempts in your future posts.

Comment: See the [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle)

Answer (score 2):

Hint: How many pairs of positive integers are there that add up to 101?

Comment: so in 51 integers there will be atleast 1 pair

Comment: @PiyushDivyanakar Exactly